# If I have multiple clients subscribed to a pusher channel, can I have only one of them receive the message?

Tags: pusher

I have a load balanced situation, in which I have multiple instances running. I'm subscribing to a channel in each instance, but I only want one of them to trigger when a message comes through.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: How will you know which instance should be the one to trigger? Will it be determined in advance, or will it simply be the first to receive such an event?

Comment: The first would be fine since I can't determine in advance because they spin up dynamically.

Comment: Violates pub, sub. Producer, consumer looks like a better pattern.

Comment: RabbitMq achieves this using a topic exchange. It might for you as well: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have different subscribers and some are only interested in a subset of the messages distributed by a your publisher. Then your messaging service must allow subscribers to specify the topics relevant for them and/or inspect the messages and specify the content they are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

that kind of goes against pub/sub pattern. Even if you added a streaming application in between you channel and your clients, this will still need to read all messages to decide which one to filter out to different clients

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, for example, Android or IOS notifications, then you are able to store `push tokens` in your database, filter them and send a message only selected users.

P.S. It could help if you provide more details about the environment of push notifications you ask, and an architecture of the application you develop.